# Excel function doesn't write anything

Tags: excel, vba

Goodmorning, i wanted to do a macro in Excel that multiply the element on the right for every element on the left (then put the result in another column), till a blank cell.
This is an example of the elements:
[enter image description here][1]

And this is what i try to write with no result...it seems like the cycle goes well, but it doesn't write anything ... could you please help me out? Anyway, sorry for my bad English, i hope i made it clear.
Thank you.

```
Sub test()
Range(A1).Select
x = 1
y = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        If IsEmpty(Ax) = True Then
            y = x + 1
        End If
                    
        If IsEmpty(Ax) = False Then
            Cells(E, x).Value = Cells(A, x).Value * Cells(D, y).Value
        End If

    x = x + 1
        
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: You're using `Cells` wrong. Should be `Cells(x, "E")` and `Cells(x, "A")` and `Cells(y, "D")`. I'm guessing `Ax` should be `Cells(x, "A")`.

Comment: Ohhh i see, sorry but this is the first time i try to "programming". 
Thank you really much Sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put the cell references as strings.

VBA will interpret Range(A1) as whatever variable A1 is set to. It is NOT the "A1" cell in your spreadsheet.

Correct is

```
Range("A1").Select
```

Similarly if you have a variable x, and want to get the cell reference A1 then you need to do something like this:

```
x=1
if IsEmpty("A" & x) then ...
```

Also, the Cells(row,column) function uses row first, then column.

I'm assuming you have "On Error Resume Next" somewhere in your code, as what you have written should throw up a lot of errors.

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you!
It works now! I thought that the code was wrong of course, because it didn't do anything, but, 0 error detected.
Maybe its the version of Excel, i dont't know, i'm at the first experience with this and without an error check i couldn't tell what was wrong or not ahah, thank you again!